# Combine data from previous and current record in sql query

Tags: delphi

Let me explain with an example. I have the following table:

```
1.    2010    100     
2.    2011    200
3.    2012    150
4.    2013    300
```

I need to have a result set like the following:

```
1.    2010    100    200
2.    2011    200    150
3.    2012    150    300
4.    2013    300    500
```

As you can see, the result should have a second column which value is the first column of the following record. I am working in Delphi and with the BDE, therefore with a local SQL.

I did not find a way to do this. In case this cannot be done in local SQL, I wonder whether this could be done in SQLite

Comment: '2010 100' is one column?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking :(

Comment: Are the values '2010 100', '2011 200' in one field or two?

Comment: Probably two. But @Stark: and the 1. etc are not columns I guess? BTW It helps to give column names.

Comment: Is it `[delphi]` or `[sql]` question? What is "previous row" for the very first row? Vagueness, vagueness...

Comment: Year and Balance are the dataset fields that are concerned with my question, which is a Sql question. If it can be done with local Sql then the resulting set would be the input to a report. I didn't want to do it with code.

Answer (score 2):

The following works in MS Sql Server

```
select
  t1.id,
  t1.year,
  t1.amount,
  coalesce((select amount from table_1 t2 where t2.year = t1.year + 1), 0) as nextyearamount
from
  table_1 t1
order by
  t1.year
```

giving

```
id          year        amount      nextyearamount
----------- ----------- ----------- --------------
1           2010        100         200
1           2011        200         150
1           2012        150         300
1           2013        300         0
```

so I would expect it or something v. similar to work in Sqlite.  Whether it works in the BDE is another matter - my recollection of it was that it was fairly miserable at anything other than simple SELECTs.  Try it and see.

Btw, it's a matter of design choice what you do for the latest year's 4th column, nextyearamount, - I've set it to zero.  It would only be 500 for 2013 if the 2014 amount were that, of course.

If you would rather do it in code rather than Sql, and you're using a TClientDataSet or another dataset type that supports fkInternalCalc fields (for the NextYearAmount one), you could do it like this:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  NextYearAmount : Variant;
begin
  VarClear(NextYearAmount);
  CDS1.Open;  //  NB must be ordered by the Year field
  CDS1.Last;
  while not CDS1.Bof do begin
    if NextYearAmount <> UnAssigned then begin
      CDS1.Edit;
      CDS1.FieldByName('NextYearAmount').Value := NextYearAmount;
      CDS1.Post;
    end;
    NextYearAmount := CDS1.FieldByName('Amount').Value;
    CDS1.Prior;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to torture sql - add calculated column, run through dataset and init it with value required. Running backwards is not a common scenario, so I did not check this approach:

```
PriorValue := 0;

with MyDataset do
begin
  Last;
  PriorValue := <dataset>.FieldValue['MyValue_Col_1'];
  // Note: you have to do something with the very last row;
  Prior;

  while not BOF do
  begin
    Edit;
    FieldValues['MyValue_Col_2'] := PriorValue;
    PriorValue := FieldValues['MyValue_Col_1'];
    Prior;
  end;
end;
```

Better solution would be to sort it upside down and loop forward (`First`, `Next`, `EOF`).

Comment: You can do it in code for sure but it wouldn't cost much to do it in sql